# Backend Error with Google Admin SDK Group Settings having "/" in Group Email Id/Address

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer, google-groups-settings

i m having issues with GWS API Group Settings when group email (when use as groupUniqueId) having a "/" character as part of the email id. Python code below:

```
service = gws_service('groupsettings') # internal func that initiate the service
results = service.groups().get(groupUniqueId = "xxxxxx/xx@xxxx.com").execute()
```

above code will return "Not Found" error.

I tried using the online API try page (from the Group Settings API documentation page) will produce http 500 with "Backend Error" xml as attached below:

[Google Online API Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH8O1.png)

I think there is bugs/issues related to Groups email having a "/" character as part of the group email id, for Group Settings API either via online or using the Python client lib package.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, i need to replace "/" character with "%2F" when making queries using group settings API